# Does AWS Redshift support a replica?

Tags: amazon-redshift

We are working with AWS Redshift DB and would like to create an online replicate (such that is fully updated with changes as well)?

The reason is that we wish to have a separate environment for one of our departments to run their own queries, and as they might "go crazy" and do some super-complex queries (they need free style, and I can't control what will they do), I don't want it to overload the main Redshift and take up all the resources for my main users. A replica will solve it as it will create an environment of their own.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not have replication between two redshift clusters like we do in mysql.

You can can use WLM in redshift and create query queues.

create user groups and query groups assign more cpu/more memory and more concurrency to production users and assign less concurrency and less memory to your department users so that your production users will not be affected.

Comment: Hi Sandesh, do you know is this still true as of Feb 2017?

Comment: server to server replication like mysql is not there. you can add snapshot for your cluster so that it saves copy in s3 .You can launch new cluster using the snapshot, but syncing between two clusters is not possible yet ( like mysql - master slaves )